What does "nach wie vor" mean?
Can you please tell what nach wie vor means. Below is the sentence I came across the phrase in.

Drei Prozent Neuverschuldung und 60 Prozent Gesamtverschuldung gemessen an der Wirtschaftsleistung (BIP) sind nach wie vor die Kriterien, auch im renovierten Fiskalpakt.

Without nach that obviously means as before, but what kind of meaning nach conveys there?

This can be answered by a dictionary.

@guidot - I don't think non-German speakers would necessarily know "nach wie vor" is a fixed phrase which might have it's own dictionary entry. Perhaps some explanation of how "nach" + "wie" + "vor" comes to mean "still" would answer the question.

To elaborate my previous comment:
nach wie vor is a fixed phrase. It emphasizes, that nothing changed in the mean time. The criteria for debt are still exactly how they were before, here meaning as they were before the revised fiscal law became effective.
Possibly this phrase is the result of some sort of contraction form nach dem Zeitpunkt ebenso wie vorher.

... wie vor ...

on its own, i.e. without nach sounds strange, and should be changed to wie vorher or wie zuvor.

To add to @guidots answer: The meaning of the phrase is "after as well as before" and stresses the fact that something hasn't changed and remains the same. Stripping down your example:

Die Kriterien sind nach wie vor 3 Prozent ...

So the criteria remain the same (and, implied, they do despite someone might think they should).
